# Guardar 3 FileUpload a la vez

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola quiero guardar 3 archivos fileupload a la vez por ahora me guarda solo 1 .

```
public string ArchivoDocumento(string nombreArchivo, FileUpload fileUpload){

    AfiliadoEL obj = (AfiliadoEL)Session["user"];
    string retorno = "Archivo no valido";

    nombreArchivo = "("+"DOCUMENTOS"+"_"+obj.nombre_afiliado.ToString()+obj.apellido_afiliado.ToString()+")";
    string Extension = Path.GetExtension(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
    string FolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folderDocumentos2"];
    string path = FolderPath;

    if (fileUpload.HasFile){
        if (Extension == ".pdf"){
            if (File.Exists(path)){
                var pathDestino = Server.MapPath(path);
                var PathFinal = Path.Combine(pathDestino, nombreArchivo + ".pdf");
                fileUpload.SaveAs(PathFinal);
                retorno = path + "/" + nombreArchivo + ".pdf";
            } else {
                var pathDestino = Server.MapPath(path);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathDestino);
                var PathFinal = Path.Combine(pathDestino, nombreArchivo + ".pdf");
                fileUpload.SaveAs(PathFinal);
                retorno = path + "/" + nombreArchivo + ".pdf";
            }
        }

    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El control `FileUpload` tiene la propiedad

[FileUpload.AllowMultiple](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.allowmultiple?view=netframework-4.7.2)

que deberias poner en `true` para poder subir multiples archivos

Entonces cuando accedas al controls podrias iterar los

[FileUpload.PostedFiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_FileUpload_PostedFiles)

algo como ser

```
foreach(var file in fileUpload.PostedFiles){
    //codigo
}
```

la funcionalidad aplica como en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no me funciona con el fileupload.allowmultiple estimado

Comment: que seria el "no funciona" ? desde el browser no te permite la seleccion multiple o en el servidor no recibes la seleccion de varios archivos

Comment: la seeccion multiple aplica como se muestra en la imagen que adjnto en la respuesta

Comment: Sale q espera pero luego se borra la ventaanaa

Comment: no entiendo, que espera que cosa? se borra la ventana? inentaste en otro browser

Comment: osea ingreso todos los archivos que quiero guardarlo en una carpeta y solo me guarda la primera .

Comment: No veo que tiene que ver que pongas los archivos en una carpeta, si estos debes seleccionarlo para realizar el upload al servidor web. Recuerda que debes iterar la propiedad PostedFiles como indique en la respuesta